# INPUT_VALIDATION script error in default Sign Up page: MSAL, AAD B2C, WPF

Tags: wpf, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using MSAL in a WPF client and trying to sign up a new user via AAD B2C. I have a Sign up or Sign in policy in AAD B2C that uses the default UI.

The user is presented the Sign Up page after a call to AcquireTokenAsync in the WPF app. The user enters his/her email and clicks the Send Code button. At this point, as soon as the user moves away from the Sign Up page a script error pops up: "Unable to get property 'INPUT_VALIDATION' of undefined or null reference.

The WPF app is coded follow this example: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-desktop/

Note that this error does not occur if the page is launched from the "Run Now" in the Policy editor in the Azure Portal. (The page comes up in my default browser, Firefox.)

Also note that if I fiddle long enough with the UI I'm able to successfully get the user signed up. (User shows in AAD B2C and can subsequently log in successfully.)

I'm not sure if this is my error, an error in the default AAD B2C sign up page, or in whatever browser control MSAL is using in this case.

Can anyone help?